# If $A$ is real symmetric and invertible then $|Ax|\geq C|x|$ for some $C>0$

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, inequality

Suppose $A$ is a real symmetric invertible matrix. I have seen the following claim that I cannot prove:

There exists $C>0$ such that $\|Ax\|\geq C\|x\|$, $x\in \mathbb{R}^{n}$.

I also have a question of my own:
Is it true that, for such a matrix $A$, we have

$$|x^T A x|\geq C \|x\|^{2}$$
for some $C>0$ ?

Here $|\cdot|$ denotes the absolute value and $\|\cdot\|$ denotes the Euclidean norm.
Notice that $A$ is not necessarily positive definite.

Any hints would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, suppose $A$ is a rectangular matrix (which is not necessarily square or symmetric). Since $f:u\mapsto \|Au\|$ is a continuous function, on the unit sphere $S=\{u:\|u\|=1\}$ (which is compact), $f$ must attain global minimum at some $u_0\in S$. Hence $\|Au\|\ge C:=\|Au_0\|$ for all unit vector $u$. In turn, $\left\|A\frac{x}{\|x\|}\right\|\ge C$ for all nonzero vector $x$. That is, $\|Ax\|\ge C\|x\|$ for all $x\ne0$. Clearly this inequality also holds for $x=0$. Therefore $\|Ax\|\ge C\|x\|$ for all $x$.

If you have a chance to learn singular value decomposition, you will see that the best constant $C$ is given by the smallest singular value of $A$.

As $u_0$ is a nonzero vector, if $A$ has full column rank (this includes the special case where $A$ is an invertible square matrix), $Au_0$ must be nonzero. Hence $C=\|Au_0\|>0$.

The inequality $|x^TAx|\ge C\|x\|^2$ is not true when $A$ is an invertible symmetric matrix. Consider e.g. $x^TAx=0$ when $A=\pmatrix{1\\ &-1}$ and $x=(1,1)^T$. It is true, however, when $A$ is positive semidefinite.

Answer (score 3):

We don't even need $A$ to be symmetric, it's enough that $A$ is invertible.

Note that for any matrix $B$ we have $\forall x: \|Bx\| < \|B\| \|x\|$.

As $A$ is invertible, we can write $\|x\| = \|A^{-1} Ax\| \leq \|A^{-1}\|\cdot \|Ax\|$ and thus $\|Ax\| \geq \frac{1}{\|A^{-1}\|}\cdot \|x\|$.

For the second question - no. Consider, for example, $A = \begin{pmatrix} -1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$ and $x = \begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}$. Then $x^T A x = 0$, but $\|x\| > 0$.

Comment: The first part is fine. The second part is not. I am asking about the absolute value  $|x^T Ax|$ not $x^TAx$.

Comment: Adding absolute value changes the question, but the answer is still negative. Changed example for this.